# 403 Permission Denied when trying to read Secrets from Vault using GCP IAM auth

Tags: amazon-web-services, hashicorp-vault, google-cloud-iam, spring-cloud-vault-config

I am using GCP IAM auth method to authenticate against vault. I followed the steps as suggested in [vault gcp auth](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/gcp.html)to authenticate using a Service Account

I was able to successfully authenticate and login. But when I try to read the secrets from the specified path, it says permission denied.

```
$vi test-policy.hcl

path "secret/test/*" {
     capabilities = ["read"]
}
```

I have the below roles assigned to my Service Account.

1. Service Account Admin
2. Service Account Key Admin
3. Service Account Token Creator

```
vault kv get secret/test/awskeys
Error reading secret/data/test/awskeys: Error making API request.

URL: GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/secret/data/test/awskeys
Code: 403. Errors:

* 1 error occurred:
* permission denied
```

I have the same issue using the spring-cloud-vault application as well. Is there any role that I missed to assign to this Service Account or am I setting the policy wrong?

Note: Vault Server is setup on AWS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was the policy setting. I updated it to below and it worked! Specific path instead of *.

```
path "secret/data/test/awskeys" {
  capabilities = ["read"]
}
```

Comment: where did u edit this?